# QT creator and iconv

Tags: qt-creator, libiconv

I have QT creator project, that has CMarkup library, that uses iconv library. On OSX 10.8.4 I'm having widespread issue with iconv library:
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_iconv", referenced from:
...
"_iconv_close", referenced from:
...
"_iconv_open", referenced from:
...`
This is caused according to Stack's few QA's by not proper build of iconv. So I compiled correct one, but now there is a question that I cannot solve: how can I swap iconv in QT creator project from /usr/lib to /usr/local/lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was obvious, if someone would need this, here is my solution. Add this line to your .pro file:
`LIBS += =L/usr/local/lib -liconv`
Do not forget to swap iconv.h file from system one, just add it into your project and write:
`#include "iconv.h"`
instead of
`#include <iconv.h>`
Hope this will help someone to save some time.
Cheers!